# Custom theme not working in Magento 2.3. As well as the default.xml

Tags: magento2.3, custom-theme

It seems that my custom theme is not working as well as my default.xml. For now, I am trying to remove the copyright part for Luma but when I override the existing theme, my default.xml is not working.

Here is the code for my default.xml

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="logo">
     <argument>
        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/dad.svg</argument>
        <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Tienda Theme</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
      </argument>
   </referenceBlock>
   <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: did you selected your new created theme in backend ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya yes. The theme it self does not work. I modified the database but stil no result. I also ran the magento commands on cmd but it does not also work.

Comment: you've created your custom theme or you're using any paid theme ?